# Firefox crashed with SIGSEGV

Tags: firefox, crash, 15.10

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

I already reinstalled Firefox.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SIGSEGV (SIGnal SEGmentation Violation) signal is sent to a process when the process accesses an area of the memory which shouldn't have accessed; so that's a bug in Firefox.

Possible solutions are upgrading to a version of Firefox in which the bug was fixed or downgrading to a version of Firefox in which the bug wasn't present; however none of the two is easily accomplishable, as that Firefox version is the only Firefox version present in the default repositories;

A solution would be uninstalling the version of Firefox from the default repositories and installing Firefox from the Mozilla repository, hoping that that specific bug was fixed:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

However this will install the bleeding edge version of Firefox, which might have other bugs.

If this version is working well enough however, you can stick to it until an update for the Firefox version in the default repositories is available, remove this version and reinstall the version from the default repositories.